# column 'name' does not exist

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

im developing an application and I have faced with this problem,i did everything and but still no solved,it contains an **`error = "column 'name' does not exist"`**
if possible give me some tips to solve this problem
I deleted the database in phone also,
please help me out
thanks in advance.

```
public class DataBaseBON {
      String TAG;
      private  Context ourContext;
      private  dbhelper ourhelper;
      private  SQLiteDatabase ourdatabase;
      public final static String KEY_ID= "_id";
      public final static String KEY_NUMBER="blockednumbers";
      public final static String N_NAME="name";
      public final static String DATABASE_NAME="databasebon.db";          
      public final static String DATABASE_TABLE="tabledb";
      public final static int DATABASE_VERSION=2;
      private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
                + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ID
                + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                + N_NAME + " text not null,"
                + KEY_NUMBER
                + " text not null);";


      public class dbhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

          public dbhelper(Context context) {    //?
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(dbhelper.class.getName(),
                    "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

      }

      public DataBaseBON(Context c){

          ourContext =c ;
      }

      public DataBaseBON open() throws SQLException{
          ourhelper = new dbhelper(ourContext);
          ourdatabase = ourhelper.getWritableDatabase();
          ourdatabase=ourhelper.getReadableDatabase();
          return this;
      }

      public void close(){
          ourhelper.close();
      }

      public long creatEntry(String inputnumber , String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NUMBER, inputnumber);
        cv.put(N_NAME, name);
        Log.v(inputnumber, "adding to Database");
        return ourdatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }


      public Cursor getcursor() {

        String[] columns = new String[]{ N_NAME, KEY_NUMBER };
        Cursor c=ourdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        return c;}


    public String[]   getcloumns() {

        String[] columns = new String[]{ N_NAME, KEY_NUMBER };

        return columns ;
    }

    public int[]  getto() {
        String TAG = null;
        int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2  };
        Log.v(TAG, "get to is ok");
        return to ;
    }
     public String[]  getdata3(String[] result) {
        String TAG = null;
        String[] columns = new String[]{ N_NAME, KEY_NUMBER };
        Cursor c=ourdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(N_NAME);
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NUMBER);
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String[] result1= new String[] {c.getString(iName),c.getString(iRow)};
        Log.v(TAG, "is ok");
        }

        return result; 

             }
```

Error :

```
11-25 23:49:33.633: E/AndroidRuntime(4072): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to startactivity 
ComponentInfo{vahid.engineer.com/vahid.engineer.com.BlackNumbersBlockDb}: 
            java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'name' does not exist
```

Comment: Is your table being created ? Did you check that ?

Comment: Try sqlite browser and verify LIVE that your tables are being created http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/

Comment: when I run it without the column "name" its working in my phone and i can see the DB, but when I try to add name i faced with this problem, I changed the DB version to 3 ,now I have new error which is AndroidRuntime(5003): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Comment: have you tried changing the columns names? does the log have any errors while executing the onCreate method? (perhaps a try/catch statement will help)

Answer (score 2):

You need this line on your dbhelper

```
this.db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Otherwise the onCreate is not being called. Notice that you need a 'Database db' variable too

http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-creating-a-sqlite-database

Comment: thanks for ur answer, but i did it before in this part :

public DataBaseBON open() throws SQLException{
          ourhelper = new dbhelper(ourContext);
          ourdatabase = ourhelper.getWritableDatabase();
          ourdatabase=ourhelper.getReadableDatabase();
          return this;
      }

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but better late than never I had such problem and I am using content provider so when you are projecting the table's attributes any attribute not projected will not be visible to the base uri so to correct that issue project all attributes of a table `projectionMap.put(Tablename.Attribute1, Tablename.Attribute1) ;`